# What is this font used in many academic papers and notes?

Tags: font-identification

I have been trying hard to get the same serif font that seems to be the standard my professors use to write lecture notes and research papers. Does anyone know what exactly it is? Ive tried Times New Roman but can't make it look similar to this, TNR is much thicker! Please help

[image]

Comment: Did you try LaTex ?

Comment: @scaaahu omg youre right, it is LATEX! just checked. tried the download link it says 2.2 gb, is this right or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: 2.2 gb sounds about right. We have a sister site http://tex.stackexchange.com/ in case you need help.

Comment: Note that LaTeX isn't just a font, it's a complete typesetting system, and it's very different from word processors such as Microsoft Word.  Many find it superior, but learning the system and converting your document won't be quick and easy.  If you just want to use the font with Word, see [this question on TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/make-ms-word-document-look-like-it-has-been-typeset-in-latex).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typesetting.  Perhaps it should be migrated to the latex SE site.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ive just installed LaTeX and gotten familiarized with most of the basics. for what i want it to do for my current assignment, ( 30% math equations and 70% plain words), it doesnt look like itll take me more than 2 or 3 hours to get it ready. your font with word looks like its a good idea but i might as well get used to latex .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [Computer Modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern), which is the default font family of LaTex.